# Garbage Collection of Objects which contains threads or ExecutorServices

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-threads

If I have a class Foo of which an instance can create a thread if I call the method `doSomething()` and I have a list of instances of Foo in my main thread.

```
class Foo()
{
    private Thread t;

    public void doSomething()
    {
        t = new Thread(() ->  {
            while(!isInterrupted())
            {
                //do something
            }

        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

1. If I understand it correctly, if I remove one of the instances of Foo from my list it will not be garbage collected if I called the method `doSomething` before and the instance created a thread?

As a consequence I have to add a method in Foo like:

```
public void stop()
{
    if(t != null)
    {
        t.interrupt();
    }
}
```

2. If I call this method after I remove the instance from the list, the instance and the thread (which is no longer running) will become available to the GC?

If I have instead of the thread a `ExecutorService` in Foo like:

```
scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
sf = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {/*do something*/}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

3. Is that the same behaviour? Do I have to call also the `stop` method?

The `stop` method will look in this case something like this:

```
public void stop()
{
    if(sf != null)
    {
        sf.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: A Thread keeps itself alive and any object it strongly references.

Comment: Instead of cancelling the task I would shutdownNow() the executor service in case it is ever used for something else in the future.

Comment: Your first comment is actually the answer of my question, so you maybe put it in an answer. In my case, if I call stop() I have no longer any usage for the instance and the task, so I could cancel it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in all cases yes (see Peter Lawrey's comment's beyond the questions).